# Strange issue - Unable to uninstall WPS Office in Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: wps-office

Tried below commands:

```
    #dpkg --get-selections | grep wps-office   [ NO OUTPUT ]

    # snap remove wps-office
      nnap "wps-office" is not installed

   # apt-get purge kingsoft-office
     Reading package lists... Done
     Building dependency tree       
     Reading state information... Done
     E: Unable to locate package kingsoft-office

   # apt-get remove wps-office
     Reading package lists... Done
     Building dependency tree       
     Reading state information... Done
No apt package "wps-office", but there is a snap with that name.
Try "snap install wps-office"
```

In some forms they suggested to remove `'libwps-0.4-4:amd64'` , but I don't think that is not connected with WPS-Office, because that package I found in an another system which don't have WPS Office`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To uninstall the WPS Office snap via the terminal:

```
sudo snap remove wps-2019-snap
```

Comment: That's what I get for answering the question before coffee. Apologies ...

Comment: So any difference in installing wps-office using this commands `snap install wps-2019-snap` and `snap install wps-office`